# autoKrige - Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '....' not found

Tags: r, automap

I have a question about the package Automap.

I have tried the ordinary kriging without problems with my data and worked fine. But when I tried the Universal Kriging a got an error message that I couldn’t understand.

I think it could be simple, but I don’t know why the function did not find the ‘silt_clay.'

Thank you.

Above my code:

```
library(automap)
data_interpol<-read.table("merge_guaiba_ceco2.txt", header=T)
head(data_interpol)
   long     lat depth silt_clay    avgran pcsand    om
1 471699 6680184   1.9    51.626 0.6683944 48.313 11.50
2 473777 6679430   1.8    57.810 0.6669483 42.186  8.80
3 471931 6679087   2.4    54.625 0.6718675 45.370  9.30
4 471337 6678456   1.9     2.887 0.4128039 97.113  0.00
5 472936 6678421   2.5    49.136 0.6344626 50.864  9.90
6 473945 6678482   1.9    99.614 0.9984355  0.386  9.45

coordinates(data_interpol)<- ~long+lat
kriging_om = autoKrige(om~ 1, data_interpol, grid4)# works fine
kriging_om_Universal= autoKrige(om~ silt_clay + avgran + pcsand, data_interpol, grid4)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'silt_clay' not found # my error

####code to obtain grid4:
    grid <- raster( )
    grid <- raster(ncol=1544, nrow=1056, xmn=468318.3, xmx=499998.3, ymn=6634918, ymx=6681238) projection (grid) <- '+proj=utm +zone=22 +south +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs ‘
    res(grid) <- 30
    grid4 <- as(grid, ‘SpatialPoints’)
```

Editing to discuss the error. After to change the grid the error persists:

The  `d_margin_xyz` is my new grid.

```
str(d_margin_xyz)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1628352 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ DIST_MARGIN: num [1:1628352] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 1 2
  ..@ coords     : num [1:1628352, 1:2] 468333 468363 468393 468423 468453 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 468333 6634963 499983 6681193
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

Trying again with the new grid containing the predictor to the Universal Kriging, the error appear again. Any clue?

```
kriging_om_Universal= autoKrige(om~ DIST_MARGIN, data_interpol, d_margin_xyz)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'DIST_MARGIN' not found
```

Comment: Do you have a column 'silt_clay' in `grid4`?

Comment: @Pascal is probably right. For Universal Kriging you need the values of the predictors at the prediction locations. Could you add a snippet of `grid4`?

Comment: Hi @Pascal I don't have a column 'silt_clay' in 'grid4'.

Comment: Hi @Paul Hiemstra, I added the code for 'grid4'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your prediction object, `grid4`, is only a `SpatialGrid` object with no attributes. To be able to predict using Universal kriging, you need the values of all the predictors (i.e. `silt_clay`, `avgran`, etc) on the prediction locations, i.e. as attributes to `grid4`. Your error is caused by the fact that `silt_clay` is not an attribute.

To fix this issue you need to add the attributes to `grid4`. For this you need to have some kind of area covering map of `silt_clay` and the other predictors. Than you can either convert this map to a `SpatialGrid` object with attributes, or extract the values at the locations in `grid4` from this map.

Comment: Ok! I don't have a covering map of silt_clay to use in Universal Kriging. I need a map as 'dist' as in your example on 'automap' function?

Comment: @ThiagoCesarLimaSilveira that is correct. If you do not have maps of your covariate that cover the entire prediction area, universal kriging is not possible.

Comment: Ok! Thanks @Paul Hiemstra. I have some maps that could help me. Now I'm figuring out how to add those attributes to my 'grid4'. Do you have any tip to do that? Thank you so much!

Comment: I would take a look at `overlay` or `over` from the `sp` package I believe. If you have a new concrete question, simply create a new question here on stackoverflow including a reproducible example.